# Getting customer collection with only those that are subscribed to newsletters

Tags: magento-1, customer, import, newsletter

I need to import a load of customers to a third party email company but need to only import those that are currently subscribed to newsletters.  The import itself has to be a file of customer details which I need to generate.  I know I could load up all customers into a collection and iterate through them, only inserting those that are subscribed into the import file but as we have 90000 plus customers I would rather just load the ones that are subscribed into the collection. The import itself uses an API but it needs to have the import file added as an attachment (fine doing that, just including it for information).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to join EAV collection with regular table. It is achievable with `joinTable` method of `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract` class. The forth parameter defines the `WHERE` condition because apparently you can't use `addAttributeToFilter` method here.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection();
$collection->addNameToSelect()
    ->joinTable('newsletter_subscriber', 'customer_id=entity_id', array('subscriber_status'), '{{table}}.subscriber_status=1');
```

Please let me know if something is unclear.

Comment: That looks pretty close to what I need.  I have the problem of some bad data to contend with (multiple subscription records) that messes up the collection load so I'm going to need to group them.  I also came up with 
`$newSubscribedCustomers = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection');
$newSubscribedCustomers->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('ns'=>'newsletter_subscriber'),'ns.customer_id = e.entity_id');
$newSubscribedCustomers->getSelect()->where("ns.customer_id !=''")->group('ns.customer_id');
$newSubscribedCustomers->load();`

Answer (score 0):

You can try one thing, this is the way I had do such thing previously.

Query against **newsletter_subscriber** table and get customer_id, so you have customer id then load customer data with this id.

Comment: Yeah, had considered that, was really hoping to get a customer collection straight off rather than having to iterate over records.  I might see if I can use a join when I load the collection up.

Answer (score 0):

This is an easy, fairly performant way to do it.

```
$newsletterSubscribers = Mage::getResourceModel('newsletter/subscriber_collection')
        ->addFieldToFilter('subscriber_status', array ('eq' => 1)); // 1 is subscribed
```

You can then iterate through the subscribers.