# How to get Customer collection that has subscribed to newsletter in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, newsletter-subscriber, customer-collection

I want to retrieve the customer collection that has subscribed to the newsletter, i see this [solution](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4071/getting-customer-collection-with-only-those-that-are-subscribed-to-newsletters) but this one is for Magento 1.9 , how can i achieve this in Magento 2?

Comment: Check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/311742/how-do-i-get-subscriber-information-base-on-the-subscriber-id/311745#311745

Answer (score 0):

MySQL: You should get all the customers subscribed to newsletter in `newsletter_subscriber`

Magento: Look at this module for reference `vendor/magento/module-newsletter` and then you can extend functionality for your purpose

Answer (score 0):

I might be late to the party but here is what I've found:

```
$customers = $this->customerCollectionFactory->create()
->addAttributeToSelect('*');

$customers->getSelect()->join(
['ns' => $customers->getTable('newsletter_subscriber')],
'e.entity_id = ns.customer_id',
['subscriber_status'])->where('ns.subscriber_status = ?', 1);
```